# Change php date output language

Tags: php, date, strtotime, strftime

I am using few variables to store different php dates in desired formats like following:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$todayPretty = date('d. M');
$oneMonthBefore = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 months'));
$oneMonthBeforePretty = date('d. M', strtotime('-1 months'));
$oneMonthBefore2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->oneMonthBefore .' -1 day'));
$oneMonthBefore2Pretty = date('d. M', strtotime($this->oneMonthBefore .' -1 day'));
$twoMonthsBefore = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-2 months'));
$twoMonthsBeforePretty = date('d. M', strtotime('-2 months'));
$currentMonth = date('F');
$previousMonth = date('F', strtotime('-1 months'));
```

Unfortunately I need them in a different language like danish for example so I've set up the following with no results:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "da_DK.UTF-8");
```

I've read that I have to use `strftime` function but how I should approach this when it comes to the variables that doesn't use `strtotime` in my case? Any help or guidance is more than welcomed.

Comment: Different language, as in date format or the words actually translated? (`Tuesday` = `Tirsdag`)

Comment: I need the words :) I was using `str_replace` but that's overkill :(

Comment: Have you tried `echo strftime('%d. (%A) %B', strtotime('-1 months'));` ?

Comment: @Glavić I had tried it but with no success

Comment: @Glavić english names for day and week - 17. (Friday) October

Comment: Are you trying this code on windows?

Comment: I had tried to setlocale for windows, linux or universal with no results. My best guess is that the locale for danish is not installed on my server.

Comment: Have you tried `setlocale(LC_ALL, "da_DK.UTF-8", 'Danish_Denmark', 'Danish');` ?

Comment: @Glavić I've fix the issue by installing the danish locale on my server via commandline :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you should check if you have installed your locale with:

```
locale -a
```

in commandline.

if not you can do that on ubuntu/debian with:

```
sudo locale-gen da_DK.UTF-8
```

In PHP you can also trying multiple deff's if your code will develop on windows and deploy on linux, like this:

```
<?php
setlocale (LC_ALL, 'de_DE.UTF-8', 'de_DE@euro', 'de_DE', 'de', 'ge', 'de_DE.ISO_8859-1', 'German_Germany');
```

Comment: I have tried with the following code to see if german for example is installed:
`date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
$loc=setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE@euro', 'de_DE', 'deu_deu');
echo strftime('%B');` and it seems that is still giving me the month names in english

Comment: You must install all locales you need on command line in your distribution. What kind you have  ? Debian, Ubuntu, ...?

Answer (score 1):

For Universal:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,'nl_NL.UTF-8');
```

For windows

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,'nld_nld');
```

For linux

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL');
```

---

> If this don't work, then you have to create a snippet [[!setlocale]]
>   and put in this:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,'nl_NL.UTF-8');
```

And call this snippet in front of your `!DOCTYPE` or `html` 
call